# Request to OneDrive fails

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get response from

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive

but so far all I am getting is exception

> Uncaught exception 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException' with message 'Unable to resolve template token'

I am using [this](https://github.com/thenetworg/oauth2-azure) Azure Active Directory oauth2 library that was recommended in documentation.

After obtaining access token I try to call

`$this->provider->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive',$_SESSION['access_token']);` but that only throw exception. If I use

`$this->provider->get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',$_SESSION['access_token']);`

It returns informations about user account.

This is the error message that I am getting.

```
[message:protected] => Unable to resolve template token
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 500
[file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\OneDrive\vendor\thenetworg\oauth2-azure\src\Provider\Azure.php
[line:protected] => 68
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\OneDrive\vendor\league\oauth2-client\src\Provider\AbstractProvider.php
                [line] => 644
                [function] => checkResponse
                [class] => TheNetworg\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Azure
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
                            (
                                [reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Internal Server Error
                                [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 500
                                [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Cache-Control] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => private
                                            )

                                        [Transfer-Encoding] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => chunked
                                            )

                                        [Content-Type] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => application/json
                                            )

                                        [request-id] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 7fc5c1c8-bd33-4788-bae9-5887d261c8c5
                                            )

                                        [client-request-id] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 7fc5c1c8-bd33-4788-bae9-5887d261c8c5
                                            )

                                        [x-ms-ags-diagnostic] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_2","ADSiteName":"AMS"}}
                                            )

                                        [Duration] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 177.0851
                                            )

                                        [Date] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Mon, 06 Feb 2017 12:55:27 GMT
                                            )

                                    )

                                [headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
                                    (
                                        [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                                        [transfer-encoding] => Transfer-Encoding
                                        [content-type] => Content-Type
                                        [request-id] => request-id
                                        [client-request-id] => client-request-id
                                        [x-ms-ags-diagnostic] => x-ms-ags-diagnostic
                                        [duration] => Duration
                                        [date] => Date
                                    )

                                [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
                                [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
                                    (
                                        [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #79
                                        [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 237
                                        [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                                        [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                                        [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
                                        [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
                                        [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [error] => Array
                                    (
                                        [code] => InternalServerError
                                        [message] => Unable to resolve template token
                                        [innerError] => Array
                                            (
                                                [request-id] => 7fc5c1c8-bd33-4788-bae9-5887d261c8c5
                                                [date] => 2017-02-06T12:55:28
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

So it returns status code 500 which probably means that error is on their side. But If I try to access `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive` through https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer then I get normal response.

Also one thing I noticed is that I cannot change permission of access token. I tried to change it in Application registration portal, and also in my code I set scopes, but my token has always same permission `[scope] => Files.ReadWrite User.Read`

**EDIT:**

Here is what my request object looks like

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request Object
(
    [method:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => GET
    [requestTarget:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => 
    [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri Object
        (
            [scheme:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => https
            [userInfo:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
            [host:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => graph.microsoft.com
            [port:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
            [path:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => /v1.0/me/drive
            [query:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
            [fragment:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri:private] => 
        )

    [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => Array
        (
            [Host] => Array
                (
                    [0] => graph.microsoft.com
                )

            [Authorization] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFEUk5ZUlEzZGhSU3JtLTRLLWFkcENKbFFSTFVXOUFERTZ0X0FwV0JuMGZNSTFUbC1Mb3ZFanBSaURnNU5laEFMTVgzbkU3U18xRkNWc2pwM19scEZoekNUSTZLbnkxN01ybFg0RGpRNHVwQUNBQSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2IiwieDV0IjoiWTR1ZUsyb2FJTlFpUWI1WUVCU1lWeURjcEFVIiwia2lkIjoiWTR1ZUsyb2FJTlFpUWI1WUVCU1lWeURjcEFVIn0.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.R4KqgeI42iGjIBoeHGnUQ7Hq519kg0cPeymNsY0JoWmwd638W8MHtYqWZh4f_Yqb45SkznrypXzZPfWOdLL1QdTXhE_eItVnjdo9dS6Q-aX9DOxGo-kZONi1tWSUukpkiVafQLyEsles3uGi2QEkila1P73hPGAuCORkwPEMolLQwr33G1KSAZpB0OnvhTfghNt82_abpFiq14b5QXvrDgEQvtTtAqVZke-kOwOGTy4FJ9y50ZQ0rij9StRBq1CvVCJlcEcUZay5dRYfrLrdt8Wr-NLt1NGVayxWQ8Zlp68o7RXZ1nrGWAyLJ9ReQsP0ToCzJU2RP8n9U_batLSqew
                )

        )

    [headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => Array
        (
            [authorization] => Authorization
            [host] => Host
        )

    [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => 1.1
    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The token needs to be supplied in the request header via the Authorization property. Note that you must prepend "Bearer " to the token in the header.

`Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Update:
If you've change the scopes defined in Active Directory, you will also need to have the user re-consent to the new scopes. To force this, include `prompt=consent` in your query string.

Comment: `header = ["Authorization" => "Bearer ".$_SESSION['access_token']->getToken()];` Still getting same error

Comment: Have you confirmed this works with the [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer)?

Comment: what should I put inside Graph Explorer ?

Comment: Okay, I went through every method that I used so far and now I understand everything up to `GET` request. I am not sure if formating of header is wrong but I am still getting same error. And now I am 90% sure that I should have everything right up to my `GET` request. I edited OP with headers from `var_dump` of my request object.

Comment: If Graph Explorer is giving you the same error, that pretty much eliminates your code as the problem. There are a couple of reasons why you might be seeing this but the most likely is that this account doesn't have a OneDrive provisioned. You can check this by logging into https://portal.office.com and selecting OneDrive from the menu. If it isn't showing there then it hasn't been provisioned for this user yet.

Comment: I cannot log there, I am using my gmail, that I am also using to log into microsoft web and onedrive. With endpoint v2.0 I should be able to log with my personal acc.

Comment: I'm a bit confused then as Graph Explorer only supports AD (aka Work/School Accounts) and not the consumer Microsoft Accounts at the moment. If you're able to login to Graph Explorer then you must have a Work/School account tied to that email address.

Comment: I am not logged into graph, but I still can set request header.